# ScrollView reset position after switching view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

After I custom **Tab layout** (without using **TabView** fore more custom style) and enable to switching menu for change view, I found some issue with content in View will reset.

Example video. After I click to second tab and back to the Home tab, ScrollView in HomeView will reset offset to top.

[image]

ContentView.swift

***FYI: It's bad way that I move view instance into other class like ViewModel. I just try.***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                switch vm.currentIndexSelect {
                case 1: vm.homeView
                case 2: vm.chatView
                default: EmptyView()
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            HStack {
                Button {
                    vm.currentIndexSelect = 1
                } label: {
                    Text("Home")
                }
                Button {
                    vm.currentIndexSelect = 2
                } label: {
                    Text("Chat")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var homeView = HomeView()
    @Published var chatView = ChatView()
    @Published var currentIndexSelect: Int = 1
}
```

HomeView.swift

```
struct HomeView: View, Equatable {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1..<20) { index in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .overlay {
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the first time, I thought it was a problem with State it will re-render view inside ( re-initiate ). So I move will into view model (*Bad Idea*) instead for save instance of Views but It still doesn't work.

Has anyone ever face this problem ?

Comment: You definitely should not be storing instances of `View`s inside a view model. That will almost certainly break things (although not the cause of this one). Regarding this issue, what happens when you use `Identifiable` data instead of a range like you're doing?

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for suggestion. I already try it ( create data with :Identifiable and also try set id: \.self with range ) But it seem not working :(

Comment: cache scroll position using scroll view proxy

Comment: @SPatel Thank you for suggestion. I think it's good one approach. But It may take some inconvenient when implement like if some page has a complex ui or we have many tabs, it will take time to maintain. By the way, This is a good approach if I has not much tab. Thanks

Comment: You should not propose an answer to your question, in the question. Enter it as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Solution ( Maybe not the best and properly to use.)

**1. Use `TabView` with page style**

```
    TabView(selection: $currentIndexSelect) {
        HomeView().tag(1)
        ChatView().tag(2)
    }
    .onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```